# jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery

When I submit the form, page is refresh it self regardless of jquery codes I've wrote. Can anyone point me to where I have been wrong?

My html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/up.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="up" action="" method="post">
<input id="image" type="text" name="file"/><input id="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#submit').click(function(){
        alert('hi');
            /*some codes goes here*/
    });
});
```

When the page loads, console display this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` even i didn't call any jquery functions.

Comment: Why load two jQueries? remove the 1.2.6 and move the jQuery lib to the top of the list

Comment: And load your script after jQuery

Comment: load jquery before your js

Comment: Just a guess but I'm pretty sure the .submit() event is firing first. I think you'd need to .preventDefault() first.

Comment: This is a poorly written question and probably a duplicate, but I don't see how it fits the "too localized" category...

Comment: Because it seems to stem from mistakes and typos made in the OPs code. If it were a little less... localized, and included research into what the console said or knowledge of script-loading order, it'd be a better question that might have worth for someone else. There's also no description of what "didn't worked" means.

Comment: trigger happy closers!!! Asker is a noob and has made easily made noob mistakes

Comment: You need to bind `$("#up").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); var file ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to include your jQuery dependent scripts after jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/up.js"></script>
```

And you should only have one jQuery file.

Comment: @Janaka: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: And NOTE: You need to bind `$("#up").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); var file ....` instead of the submit button

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove your first `script`to jquery, it is a old version..

Also I think your javascript is in the `up.js` file. The file is requested before jQuery. You should load jQuery first and then your custom code..

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/up.js"></script>
```

You are also linking wrong to the `up.js` file.. You should use `../` instead of `./`, to go the parent folder.

Comment: 1.7.1 is, technically, also an old version. ;)

Comment: You are right, but not as old as 1.2.6 ;)

Comment: Oh, definitely. And good catch on the path-mistake as well. =)